# PHP cURL long execution time

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a request using cURL and the execution time is very long.
The idea is to send some parameters via the URL and when the URL sent the script in the URL's host is executed.
When I send this URL, it takes like 15 seconds to send the request.
I don't need the recieved data, that's why I used RETURNTRANSFER.

```
 function SendRequest($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Thank you,
Avi.

Comment: If you don't need the received data, you may think about doing this in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i perform a CURL exec:

```
$fp = curl_init('http://yourposturl.com');
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($fp)) ) {
curl_close($fp);
    exit;
}
curl_close($fp);
```